# Product demo using Canvas Animation

Tags: animation, canvas, demo

I love the way Sublime text shows it's product demo on it's home page: 
http://www.sublimetext.com/

How can I create a similar demo? All I note is that it is a Canvas element.

Sorry if it's sounds as a basic question. I see it's made on Canvas. Any leads or help in this regard is highly appreciate?

Comment: The one on Sublime text is done using Canvas. Gifs are slow, and large resolution images make the large sized, and fuzzy.

Comment: Are you wanting to demo your app in action--like a series of step-by-step screenshots? Or do you want simply to create an "auto-typer" where text is drawn to the canvas one letter at a time (as if being typed)? Or something else? :-)

Answer (score 1):

They are using delays and parts of images such as this one (look at the bottom part of the image):

[image]

and specify what (rectangular) part of each image renders when, making it look like an animation.

It's a typical [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).

---

This is the list of the images:

```
"anim/rename2_packed.png",
"anim/days_169_packed.png",
"anim/command_palette_packed.png",
"anim/goto_anything_packed.png",
"anim/goto_anything2_packed.png",
"anim/regex_packed.png"
```

---

And this is how they specify the delay and the image pieces

```
{"delay":1811,"blit":[[0,0,800,450,0,0]]},
{"delay":48,"blit":[[0,450,400,344,200,36],[66,982,63,15,0,36]]},
{"delay":798,"blit":[]}, etc...
```

As you see, `delay` is the time in milliseconds, and `blit` looks like parameters for `drawImage` - srcX, srcY, width, height, destX, destY.

---

Each of the "screens" is kept as a separate variable, like `command_palette_timeline`, `days_169_timeline`, `goto_anything_timeline`, etc. Each containing delay/blit array of objects like the one from the paragraph above.

---

The actual render code is pretty straightforward, they follow each step in each timeline, with delays between them, and each step is rendered like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < blits.length; ++j)
    {
        var blit = blits[j]
        var sx = blit[0]
        var sy = blit[1]
        var w = blit[2]
        var h = blit[3]
        var dx = blit[4]
        var dy = blit[5]
        ctx.drawImage(img, sx, sy, w, h, dx, dy, w, h)
    }
```